# How to Detect My iPad Devices using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Getting false value when i check my device is iPad, How can I do that; can any one help me. I've provided code below which can help.

```
var isiDevice = /android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

        if (isiDevice)
        {
            CallFullScreen();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 if( !navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ) { 

     you code goes here for samll device like iphone, androide.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code in if condition for detecting device

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // do somethig
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use below script which allow to detect many device. this script allow you to detect single or multiple device browser

```
  var isMobile = {
       Android: function() {
           return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
       },
       BlackBerry: function() {
           return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
       },
       iOS: function() {
           return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod|ipad/i);
       },
       ipad : function(){
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
       },
       Opera: function() {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
       },
       Windows: function() {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
       },
       BB: function() {
          return navigator.userAgent.match(/BB10/i);
       },
      any: function() {
          return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows() || isMobile.BB());
    }
  };


 call like below
 if(isMobile.any()) // this function gives if any mobile browser 
 if(isMobile.ipad()) // return if ipad
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var isiDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i) != null;

if (isiDevice)
{
    CallFullScreen();
}
```